# Please help to understand the part of JS code

Tags: javascript, indexof

i'm a new one in coding and learning the indexOf() method i found such part of code (see below)
I wonder why do we use the *if()* part in the code below. Why doesn't it work without it?

```
var myString = 'Welcome to Wrox books. ';
myString = myString + 'The Wrox website is www.wrox.com. ';
myString = myString + 'Visit the Wrox website today. Thanks for buying Wrox';
var foundAtPosition = 0;
var wroxCount = 0;
while (foundAtPosition != -1)
{
foundAtPosition = myString.indexOf('Wrox',foundAtPosition);
if (foundAtPosition != -1)
{
wroxCount++;
foundAtPosition++;
}
}
document.write('There are ' + wroxCount + ' occurrences of the word Wrox');
```

Will appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Well I guess you can leave the `if (foundAtPosition != -1)` out, because the loop will not run when `foundAtPosition == 1 `

Comment: @Lyudvig Bodmer, here in StackOverflow is somewhat customary to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it. Any other questions are welcome as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You need the if to check if you have found the string you are looking for.
 indexOf() will return -1 if the string is not found

Answer (score 0):

You're counting the position of `wrox` everytime you found it. If you do not have more occourences, it won't increment the counter `wroxCount` because we don't want the counter to count after the `foundAtPosition` becomes `-1`. Or in other words, after last occourence, or if `wrox` is not found at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `indexOf()` method accepts two arguments: the substring to find in the given string, and the location(index) at which it should start searching for the substring. It returns the location(index) of the first occurrence of the substring(if the second argument is provided, it will be the first one after the provided location).

So, what the code inside the loop does:

1. Finds the location of the first occurrence of the substring using the `indexOf()` method and saves the location in the variable `foundAtPosition`.
2. If the substring was found(`foundAtPosition!=-1`), the `wroxCount` variable is incremented to indicate the number of substrings found so far, and the `foundAtPosition` variable is incremented as well(read on about it).
3. The `while` loop checks the condition, and if it is satisfied it executes its contents again.
4. The loop finds the location of the first occurrence of the substring, but now it starts searching at `foundAtPosition`. As the `foundAtPosition` variable was incremented by one, it will start searching after the previously found occurrence, and will return the location of the next one.
5. This goes on until there are no more occurrences left, which leaves the `wroxCount` variable containing the number of the occurrences of the substring in the main string.

The result: you get the number of times the word(substring) you are looking for occurs in the string `myString`.